# sharepoint flow condition runs showing False always

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, choice-field, send-email

I have a SharePoint list with  "Leave type" as one of the columns which is a choice field. I have another column as "Days requested".

I created a flow that needs approval redirected to another person if Leave type is Annual Leave and it is more than 10 days Combination of IF and AND condition.

I discovered it is running as Inputs expression is False and goes to where false expression should go even if the condition is true.

I have tried several times and the problem keeps showing up. thus directing my flow to the email meant for false expression.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot, create variables and write the values of the Leave type and the expression you use to establish "more than 10 days" into these variables. Do that BEFORE the condition action.

Run the workflow and check the contents of the variables.

Now you can see what the input for the condition is and you can take appropriate steps to correct things that have gone wrong.

Comment: i did have a column that is cakled Leave Value which is a calculated colums and the value for Annual Leave in that column is 10

Comment: Sorry, I can't see your screen and I cannot see your flow logic or the condition or the commands you used. I'm trying to give you the tools for troubleshooting. You must do the checking yourself. The idea here is that you write the values into variables, then you can see why your condition results in FALSE.

Comment: I have saved the flow screeshot in my drive. here is a link . https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xAS5CmAmLwf4aPpMWVxItUNEg9paYcvs/view?usp=sharing. if you dont mind we can work together via zoom to troubleshoot

Comment: What do the variables show when you go through the flow after it has run????

Answer (score 0):

For troubleshooting, it will be better to upload screenshots of your flow configuration and the corresponding list.

As you mentioned that the if condition always returns false. Please check type and value of variables used in the if condition. In flow you can check status of each run.

Comment: MSFT I tried to upoad screeshoot but not going through. here is a link to the flow screeshoot        https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xAS5CmAmLwf4aPpMWVxItUNEg9paYcvs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AdebayoOgunmoriyele I assume the reason shall be the Days requested is a calculated column. Round the value of "Days requested" and have another try.